# Chrome doesn't see most of the local files

Tags: google-chrome, flatpak

I installed Google Chrome on Ubuntu using Flatpak. I can open only the following folders in my home directory:

```
.config/
.local/
.pki/
.var/
docs/
files/
music/
pictures/
videos/
```

If I try to open other folders or files I get ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. How can I allow Chrome to open other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Made my account just for this issue.
The fix is to install Flatseal (i'm sure there's a CLI way to do this, but i'm not sure of it) and select Google Chrome. Then, scroll down to Filesystem and enable "All user files". If you wish, it seems you can also give it access to the rest of the filesystem.

This one was bugging me!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. One also can try to use the following command to allow access to home folder: `flatpak override --user --filesystem=home com.google.Chrome` System restart (or maybe restart of all Chrome processes) may be required to activate settings.

Comment: That's great to know! I'm pretty new to flatpak. I found that with Flatseal simply restarting Chrome fixed it.